# LazyLogging vs StrictLogging

Tags: scala, scala-logging

I am using scala-logging. There are two classes LazyLogging and StrictLogging. I see, that the difference between them is that LazyLogging is initialized lazily. What is the purpose of that. When I should use one over the other and why?

Answer (score 4):

Best always use StrictLogging. LazyLogging for when you want to postpone Logger initialization.

Comment: What is a use case that would desire postponed Logger initialization? Generally, it seems like this could be nice if nothing was ever logged, but creating a logger seems pretty cheap, and creating a lazy val might result in deadlock (as I'm fussing with now). Are there better reasons to postpone logger initialization?